# Camera not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, camera

When I try to run Cheese, the camera does not work.
And if I type cheese on the Terminal, I get this error:

```
Internal data stream error.: ../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstPipeWireSrc:pipewiresrc1:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)webcam
```

This seems to be a [known bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg6022670.html) on last April, but not sure if there is a fix to it ?